# Can't install enterprise app on device with iOS 9 GM seed

Tags: ios, ipad, enterprise, ios9

I'm trying to install an enterprise app over the air on ipad 2 device with iOS 9 GM seed. iOS shows download progress, after downloading there is an error "Can't install".

It worked with the last iOS 9 beta

There is a log from console:

```
Sep 10 04:12:25 iPad-Dashboard ondemandd[145] <Error>: Application with ID: M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps was installed, but it doesn't appear to have a bundle URL, we are taking no action on this.
Sep 10 04:12:27 iPad-Dashboard ondemandd[145] <Error>: An object with ID [0x15e74230 <x-coredata:///AssetDownloads/t7E19FE36-172C-43EF-90EC-1B069309CF8B16>] has already registered.
Sep 10 04:12:27 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14deb5f0> M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7312DC34-DF53-43BA-AE3E-DEA05EBF014D/-4088318364755750305.app> withPhase:0
Sep 10 04:12:27 iPad-Dashboard lsd[74] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x16586090> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6000 / Completed: 60 of 100   to 0
Sep 10 04:12:27 iPad-Dashboard SpringBoard[47] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Sep 10 04:12:28 iPad-Dashboard MobileSafari[137] <Warning>: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
Sep 10 04:12:47 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: [Download]: Download task did finish: 5 for download: -4088318364755750305
Sep 10 04:12:47 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace] Installing download: -4088318364755750305 with step(s): Install
Sep 10 04:12:47 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Installing software package with bundleID: M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps: bundleVersion: 1.1.18.1100 path: /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-4088318364755750305/8091709402150391677
Sep 10 04:12:50 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: BundleValidator: Failed bundleIdentifier: M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps does not match expected bundleIdentifier: com.boardmaps.boardmaps
Sep 10 04:12:50 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Bundle validated for bundleIdentifier: M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps success: 0
Sep 10 04:12:50 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Uninstalling placeholder for app <LSApplicationProxy: 0x16095af0> M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7312DC34-DF53-43BA-AE3E-DEA05EBF014D/-4088318364755750305.app>
Sep 10 04:12:50 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Uninstalling app <LSApplicationProxy: 0x16095af0> M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7312DC34-DF53-43BA-AE3E-DEA05EBF014D/-4088318364755750305.app>
Sep 10 04:12:50 iPad-Dashboard installd[42] <Notice>: 0x1f081000 -[MIClientConnection uninstallIdentifiers:withOptions:completion:]: Uninstall requested by itunesstored (pid 116) with options: {
    }
Sep 10 04:12:50 iPad-Dashboard installd[42] <Notice>: 0x1f081000 -[MIUninstaller _uninstallBundleWithIdentifier:error:]: Uninstalling identifier M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps
Sep 10 04:12:50 iPad-Dashboard installd[42] <Notice>: 0x1f081000 -[MIUninstallNotifier performRemovalWithCompletionBlock:]: Destroying container with identifier M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7312DC34-DF53-43BA-AE3E-DEA05EBF014D
Sep 10 04:12:50 iPad-Dashboard installd[42] <Notice>: 0x1f081000 -[MIUninstallNotifier performRemovalWithCompletionBlock:]: Destroying container with identifier M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B7AD1744-EB1F-42D3-8690-F1FB4B2DA526
Sep 10 04:12:51 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: LaunchServies: No app bundle to remove for M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps
Sep 10 04:12:51 iPad-Dashboard lsd[74] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Sep 10 04:12:51 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: LaunchServices: clearing created progress for M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps
Sep 10 04:12:51 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Uninstalling application placeholder for bundleIdentifier: M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps; success: 1
Sep 10 04:12:51 iPad-Dashboard itunesstored[116] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Failed to install application: M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps; /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-4088318364755750305/8091709402150391677; Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=143 "(null)"
```

Comment: Getting exactly the same issue. Have cleared up the manifest as much as possible to no avail. ios-deploy from terminal works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might have had the same issue with OTA installations with iOS8 and implemented the workaround on server side: You changed the bundle ID in the plist manifest file and added board maps to it. We added .dummy to make it working with iOS 8.1

BundleValidator: Failed bundleIdentifier: M3KJ3WBD2L.com.boardmaps.boardmaps does not match expected bundleIdentifier: com.boardmaps.boardmaps

Unfortunately, it does not work with iOS 9 anymore. We ned to change the logic on server side again to differentiate between iOS 8 and 9 while the plist file is being generated.

Cheers!

Comment: We have the same identifier in plist on server. It contains the prefix of AppId plus our bundleIdentifier.

Comment: Thank you, Frood. We removed the app prefix from identifier in manifest plist on server and the app installed successfully. Do you know whether Apple changed that permanently? @endrelzr

Comment: This seems to be the right solution. With iOS8 we had to generate a unique                "bundle-identifier" where we postfixed with the build number. It's important that you *don't* do that with iOS9 (basically they have fixed the bug they introduced in iOS8 as I see it) and ensure the "bundle-identifier" in your manifest.plist is the same as your ipa file.

Comment: "We ned to change the logic on server side again to differentiate between iOS 8 and 9 while the plist file is being generated." => Since this was a problem for users who updated their device from 7 to 8 and users can only go from 7 to 9 now (8 being unavailable for install) I do not see any issue anymore. Just ignore it. I updated an app that I installed on iOS 8 from our internal hockey, and it installed fine on iOS 9. Though I forgot that we also had appended .ios8 earliere and it didn't install on iOS 9 with that bundle ID - until I found your answer here and remembered about it ;)

Comment: I am facing the same issue because the dummy bundle id for the iOS 8 bug. However I already change the bundle id to the right on in the plist file but the iPad is still showing the old bundle id in the error logs. I restarted Safari and soft reset the device but it is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Also seeing this with TestFairy. TestFairy adds ".download" to the end of your bundle identifier, causing the install to fail on devices that have iOS 9 GM pre-seed installed. This wasn't a problem with iOS 8 nor with the iOS 9 betas...

Comment: Wondering if it's related to the new PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER that Apple recommends that you use...

Comment: TestFairy differentiates iOS version, and only iOS 8.x gets the ".download" suffix.

Answer (score 2):

We found that removing the team prefix from the bundle-id helped with some downloads, but for others we had to rebuild the .ipa in XCode 7.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, go back to the way things were done pre 8.1.3.  As soon as I rebuilt our (non-downloading) enterprise apps using the 'old' techniques, they all started being downloadable OTA on 9.0

It's a bit of a PITA in as much as we now need an 8.1.3 >= < 9.0 build as well as a >= 9.0 build, but hey ho, that's Apple...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the pre 8.1.3 way? I am using the itms-services link pointing to a plist file containing the IPA link. Is this what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

> iOS 9 became more strict with the manifest information:the tag,the
>   value,or something else.

I have met the similar problem these days:

```
I find the problem is that I mistake the bundle-identifier value.
```

> I find if you mistake the bundle-identifier value,the iOS 9 will not allow you to install the app,but iOS 8 or lower version will not check bundle-identifier value.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue with iOS 9 GM. I eventually find out that the problem was caused by the zip version of the ipa.

I was using a Java library to generate the ipa. Now I use `/usr/bin/zip` to generate the ipa and it solves my problem.

Using `file` command I can see that both zip tools are not generating the same zip version :

```
$ file working_with_ios9gm.ipa
working_with_ios9gm.ipa: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract

$ file not_working_with_ios9gm.ipa
not_working_with_ios9gm.ipa: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, sat until maybe 4 AM. Some sleep and coffee, and I spotted it:
in the manifest.plist, there are 3 assets dictionary entries:
"software-package","full-size-image","display-image".

The "full-size-image" entry had a comma instead of a point in the URL:
`<string>https://www.myserver,com/AppIcon512.png</string>`

Changed to a point and now adhoc downloading works again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by setting the bundler-identifier value to the exact value that is set in the xcode build settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a special character in the ipa file name. Finally I removed the special character (é) and I deployed again, and it worked fine.